# Syntax error in IE11 with vue.js, webpack and babel

Tags: webpack, vue.js, eval, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I'm trying to get a demo to work and it works fine in Chrome but fails in IE11.

The syntax error is related to an eval() but is only an issue with IE11. An example of the issue can be seen here (view with IE11):

> [Example site not working in IE11.](http://coreui.io/demo/Vue_Demo/)
>
> [The source is located
>   here.](https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template/tree/master/Vue_Full_Project)

**I have modified the .babelrc file to look like:**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["istanbul"]
    }
  }
}
```

My webpack.base.conf.js file has been changed to include the babel-polyfill but nothing seems to help fix the issue.

```
app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js']
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: In case anyone was interested I fixed this by using the promise polyfill on any page using promises:
import 'core-js/fn/promise'

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. In my case, it was because I am using coffeescript in `.vue` : `lang="coffee"`.
The script was not converted to ES5, so I edited `vue-loader.conf.js` to transpile the coffeescript.

I have built this project by `vue-cli` + `vuejs-templates/webpack`

"build/utils.js"

```
exports.scriptLoaders = function (options) {
  options = options || {}

  const coffeeLoader = {
    loader: 'coffee-loader',
    options: {
      transpile: {
        presets: ['env', 'es2015']
      }
    }
  }

  const jsLoader = {
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  }

  return {
    js: jsLoader,
    coffee: coffeeLoader
  }
}
```

"build/vue-loader.conf.js"

```
module.exports = {
  loaders: Object.assign({},
    utils.cssLoaders({
      sourceMap: isProduction
        ? config.build.productionSourceMap
        : config.dev.cssSourceMap,
      extract: isProduction
    }),
    utils.scriptLoaders()),
  transformToRequire: {
    video: 'src',
    source: 'src',
    img: 'src',
    image: 'xlink:href'
  }
}
```

This is the repo:
https://github.com/wataruoguchi/play-vue-cli/commit/0bdb9badf82e60696adb393bc351c48a3e69072c

I didn't use "babel-polyfill" at the end.

Comment: This helped a lot for importing .Vue files outside the root.  By default, vue-loader will use babel-loader with .babelrc but I was able to add options to the babel-loader used by vue-loader in order to resolve files outside the root.

Answer (score -3):

IE does not support arrow functions and 'syntax error' is logged in line:

```
boolean: val => (typeof val === 'string' ? val === '' || val === 'true' ? true : (val === 'false' || val === 'null' || val === 'undefined' ? false : val) : val),
```

in vendor file.

Comment: Does not provide a solution or any explanation